# Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Config<ExpressContext>'. Ben Awad tutorial

Tags: typescript, apollo-client

I am currently working on Ben Awad's React and GraphQL Fullstack tutorial.

I have run into this error in my index.ts file,

when I hover over   `const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({})`

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'Config<ExpressContext>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Config<ExpressContext>': logger, debug, cache, formatError, and 6 more.ts(2345)
```

for reference, here is my index.ts file

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer, ExpressContext } from "apollo-server-express";

const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
  await orm.getMigrator().up();

  const app = express();

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({})


  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("running on port 4000");
  });
};

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOG8I.jpg)

Comment: So what's the question? The error message is telling you flat out what is wrong.

Comment: I've tried doing what the error message says; still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({} as Config<ExpressContext>)
```

Comment: it worked, I just had to import Config - `import { Config } from 'apollo-server-core';`